# Factoring RSA weak modulus

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, modular-arithmetic, factoring

Given a public key for RSA, I have extracted the modulus which looks like this :

```
Public-Key: (2049 bit)
Modulus:
    01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02:19:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fe:
    f8:45
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
```

If we remove the first 01 for the sign, we have a 2048 modulus and we can remove the zeros. So I guess the modulus will be :

```
219FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEF845
```

My problem now is to factorize this 1036 bit modulus. I think that the FF pattern gives us a hint but I can't find it.

Could you please help?

Thank you

Comment: That leftmost byte valued `01` cannot be removed. The least significant bit in it that has been set to 1 is **not** a sign bit. It is part of the modulus value. First of a, the *most significant bit* could be a sign bit, but it is set to 0, so it doesn't contribute to the value. Second, if that 1 bit in the byte would not be part of the modulus then the key size would not be 2049 bits as the key size for RSA is *defined to be the modulus size in bits*.

Comment: Your modulus is $2^{2048}+\mathtt{0x21a}\cdot2^{1024}-\mathtt{0x107bb}$. That's special! Also, the order of magnitude of the middle coefficient is twice the square root of the negative of the right one.

Comment: [Followup question about the prime factors](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67464/555).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [fgrieu](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67384/factoring-rsa-weak-modulus#comment149110_67384) points out, the number to factor can be written as 
$$
n = 2^{2048} + 538\cdot 2^{1024} - 67515\,.
$$
We can identify this number with the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + 538x - 67515$, 
 with $n = f(2^{1024})$. Furthermore, if we factor this polynomial as $f(x) = g(x)\cdot h(x)$ then $n = f(2^{1024}) = g(2^{1024})\cdot h(2^{1024}) = p\cdot q$ since polynomial evaluation is homomorphic.

Since this is a simple quadratic equation, it is easy enough to find that $f(x) = (x - 105)(x + 643)$. Thus, the factors are $2^{1024} - 105$ and $2^{1024} + 643$.

The Fermat factorization algorithm is particularly efficient for integers whose factors are very close together. This happens to be the case here.